# wget strips parameters from url

Tags: cron, wget, directadmin

I use the following command in Directadmin:

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://www.domain-name.com/index.php?parameter=extrap&task=update
```

Now when I send an output email, it shows connecting to the URL but without &task=update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *nix operating systems, which you seem to be using, `&` is a special character that sends the process to the background. You can escape it by quoting the URL:

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null "https://www.domain-name.com/index.php?parameter=extrap&task=update"
# Here --------------------^------------------------------------------------------------------^
```